# Tossing an unfair coin: information theory

Tags: information-theory

I have an unfair coin with unknown bias $p$ chosen uniformly at random from $[0, 1]$. I keep tossing the coin multiple times and log the outcomes.

It is intuitive to see I gain more information about $p$ with each toss. But what might be an information theoretic approach to represent the situation that scales with the number of tosses?

Comment: This seems like probability distribution parameter estimation question. You should start by looking at maximum likelihood estimation and Bayesian estimation.
Otherwise this question is too vague to have specific answer.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238089/beta-distribution-on-flipping-a-coin

Answer (score 0):

The fraction of heads you get is a measure of $p$.  In the normal approximation, valid if you have a bunch of tosses and $p$ is not too close to $0$ or $1$, the standard deviation of the number of heads in $N$ tosses is $\sigma=\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$.  This gives an indication of how accurately you know $p$